# Outlook is not giving mail box email Id in OfficeContext of WebAddin

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

In some outlook mailboxes, it is not giving mailbox email Id in Office context mailbox. It is happening only for some accounts of mailbox. not for all. Has anyone encountered this issue?

What could be the reason for not getting mailbox Id?

I am trying to access email Id from user profile using below command :

```
Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress
```

I have logged entire user profile but couldn't find mailbox email Id in that.

**Office.context.userProfile:**

> {"$$d__getDisplayName$p$0": function (){return b.apply(a,arguments)},
>   "$$d__getEmailAddress$p$0": function (){return b.apply(a,arguments)},
>   "$$d__getTimeZone$p$0": function (){return b.apply(a,arguments)},
>   "$$d__getUserProfileType$p$0": function (){return
>   b.apply(a,arguments)}, "_data$p$0": {"_data$p$0": {"attachments":
>   [{"attachmentType": 0, "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
>   "id":
>   "AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAABEgAQAFZrqIFbyfBJtvjbE7hSnoo=",
>   "isInline": false, "name":
>   "citrix-xenmobile-worx-mobile-apps-overview.pdf", "size": 2282605},
>   {"attachmentType": 0, "contentType": "application/octet-stream", "id":
>   "AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAABEgAQAGNiE5qMZeBIpETDR6IMuu4=",
>   "isInline": false, "name": "xxxxxx-overview.pdf",
>   "size": 1331472}, {"attachmentType": 0, "contentType":
>   "application/octet-stream", "id":
>   "AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAABEgAQAIrqasfNYRFAnC8BKy2yZ90=",
>   "isInline": false, "name":
>   "xxxxxx-exchange-2013.pdf", 
>   "size":81489}], 
>   "cc": null, 
>   "conversationId": "AAQkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNAAQAOU92M54RSlIl2w85HL0Gag=",
>   "dateTimeCreated": 1528693025000, 
>   "dateTimeModified": 1528693026000,
>   "dateTimeSent": 1528692997000, 
>   "entities": {"Addresses": null,
>   "Contacts": null, "EmailAddresses": null, "MeetingSuggestions": null,
>   "PhoneNumbers": null, "TaskSuggestions": null, "Urls": null}, 
>   "error":false, 
>   "ewsUrl":"https://exch2016mbx01.hostingcloudapp.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx",
>   "filteredEntities": null, 
>   "from": {"address":
>   "xxxxxslxxxai@insify6.onmicrosoft.com", "appointmentResponse": 0, "name":
>   "xxxxxslxxxai@insify6.onmicrosoft.com", "recipientType": 7}, 
>   "hostVersion":"16.13.1 (180523.04)",
>
> > "id":"AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAA=",
>
> "internetMessageId": "BM1PR0101MB1378AA29CE35685ED42BF240AA780@BM1PR0101MB1378.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM",
>
> "itemClass": "IPM.Note", 
>   "itemType": 1, 
>   "location": "",
>   "normalizedSubject": "Mail room  XXXXXX",
>   "permissionLevel": 2, 
>   "restUrl": "", 
>   "sender": {"address":
>   "xxxxxslxxxai@insify6.onmicrosoft.com", "appointmentResponse": 0, "name":
>   "xxxxxslxxxai@insify6.onmicrosoft.com", "recipientType": 7}, 
>   "subject": "Mail room XXXX", 
>   "to": [{"address":
>   "YYYYYY@xyz.com", "appointmentResponse": 0, "name":
>   "YYYYYY", "recipientType": 1}], 
>    "userTimeZone": "India Standard Time",
>   "wasSuccessful": 1}, "_permissionLevel$p$0": 3}}

**outlookDiagnostics :**

```
{"host": "Outlook", "platform": "Mac", "version": "16.13.523.1"}
```

For the same account, if i open in browser it is giving below response :

```
{
    "$$d__getDisplayName$p$0": function(){
        returnb.apply(a,
        arguments)
    },
    "$$d__getEmailAddress$p$0": function(){
        returnb.apply(a,
        arguments)
    },
    "$$d__getTimeZone$p$0": function(){
        returnb.apply(a,
        arguments)
    },
    "$$d__getUserProfileType$p$0": function(){
        returnb.apply(a,
        arguments)
    },
    "_data$p$0": {
        "_data$p$0": {
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "attachmentType": 0,
                    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
                    "id": "AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAABEgAQAFZrqIFbyfBJtvjbE7hSnoo=",
                    "isInline": false,
                    "name": "citrix-xenmobile-worx-mobile-apps-overview.pdf",
                    "size": 1688944
                },
                {
                    "attachmentType": 0,
                    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
                    "id": "AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAABEgAQAGNiE5qMZeBIpETDR6IMuu4=",
                    "isInline": false,
                    "name": "citrix-xenmobile-technology-overview.pdf",
                    "size": 985344
                },
                {
                    "attachmentType": 0,
                    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
                    "id": "AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAABEgAQAIrqasfNYRFAnC8BKy2yZ90=",
                    "isInline": false,
                    "name": "citrix-netscaler-datasheet-microsoft-exchange-2013.pdf",
                    "size": 60755
                }
            ],
            "consentMetadata": null,
            "conversationId": "AAQkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNAAQAOU92M54RSlIl2w85HL0Gag=",
            "dateTimeCreated": 1528693025000,
            "dateTimeModified": 1528719978000,
            "dateTimeSent": 1528692997000,
            "endNodeUrl": null,
            "entities": {
                "Addresses": null,
                "Contacts": null,
                "EmailAddresses": null,
                "IsLegacyEntityExtraction": true,
                "MeetingSuggestions": null,
                "PhoneNumbers": null,
                "TaskSuggestions": null,
                "Urls": null
            },
            "entryPointUrl": "https://localhost:8000/web-addin/index/read",
            "ewsUrl": "https://webmail.hostingcloudapp.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx",
            "extensionId": "504c90a8-b38d-4fe7-1234-eed812c585b5msgReadOpenPaneButton",
            "filteredEntities": {},
            "from": {
                "address": "sravani@insify6.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name": "sravani@insify6.onmicrosoft.com",
                "recipientType": 3
            },
            "hostVersion": "15.1.1261.35",
            "id": "AAMkAGVhYzA1NmRmLTRiZjUtNDEwMS1hMWMxLTZlM2RjMWVhMTQzNABGAAAAAAAScTof+QIKS4tDDog5ifPPBwBc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAAAAAAEMAABc63luyEElTKdkOmKxCJ+wAACKOm4aAAA=",
            "internetMessageId": "<BM1PR0101MB1378AA29CE35685ED42BF240AA780@BM1PR0101MB1378.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>",
            "isRead": true,
            "itemClass": "IPM.Note",
            "itemType": 1,
            "marketplaceAssetId": null,
            "marketplaceContentMarket": null,
            "normalizedSubject": "Mail room  2018-06-11T10:25:53.072844",
            "overrideWindowOpen": false,
            "owaView": "ThreeColumns",
            "permissionLevel": 2,
            "restUrl": "https://webmail.hostingcloudapp.com/api",
            "sender": {
                "address": "sravani@insify6.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name": "sravani@insify6.onmicrosoft.com",
                "recipientType": 3
            },
            "subject": "Mail room  2018-06-11T10:25:53.072844",
            "timeZoneOffsets": [
                {
                    "end": 8640000000000000,
                    "offset": 330,
                    "start": -8640000000000000
                }
            ],
            "to": [
                {
                    "address": "james@xenovus-americana.com",
                    "name": "James",
                    "recipientType": 2
                }
            ],
            "userDisplayName": "James",
            "userEmailAddress": "james@xenovus-americana.com",
            "userProfileType": "enterprise",
            "userTimeZone": "India Standard Time"
        },
        "_permissionLevel$p$0": 3
    }
}
```

Outlook webclient diagnostic information :

> {     "host": "Outlook",  "platform": "OfficeOnline",     "version":
>   "16.0.8004.1000" }

If i configure same account in different machine outlook, it is working.  Also if i configure different mail account in same outlook client, that is working. This issue is coming in some specific outlook clients and mail account combination only.

Added more information to understand the issue.

Comment: When you say email Id, do you mean Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId through outlook api? This value is available in read mode only, not for compose mode. For compose, you can get such value through saveAsync. If for some accounts, the value is still not available in read mode, could you please let us know some details, such as, which environment it happens in, outlook desktop or web? Thanks

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, please check update

Comment: Thanks for raising it. We are working on towards fixing it.

Comment: @Rajeev Looks like display name is empty for this account. Can you also share the userProfile value you get on Windows/Outlook web client for the same account?

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility any update?

Comment: @Rajeev were you able to find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: nop. we are taking email id from user in these case